# Insert into django many to many table without executing select

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I want to perform a simple insert into a Django many to many table, for example:

```
INSERT INTO "chat_room_users" ("room_id", "user_id") values (35, 6)
```

Here is my **models.py**:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    ...

class Room(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='rooms')
    ...
```

and **code.py**:

```
print('start')
room = Room.objects.get(id=35)
user = User.objects.get(id=6)
room.users.add(user)
print('finish')
```

In this case Django performs 3 database queries, here is the **log**:

```
start
SELECT "chat_room"."id", "chat_room"."name", "chat_room"."disabled" FROM "chat_room" WHERE "chat_room"."id" = 35; args=(35,)
SELECT "chat_user"."id", "chat_user"."password", "chat_user"."last_login", "chat_user"."username", "chat_user"."sex" FROM "chat_user" WHERE "chat_user"."id" = 6; args=(6,)
BEGIN; args=None
SELECT "chat_room_users"."user_id" FROM "chat_room_users" WHERE ("chat_room_users"."room_id" = 35 AND "chat_room_users"."user_id" IN (6)); args=(35, 6)
INSERT INTO "chat_room_users" ("room_id", "user_id") SELECT 35, 6; args=(35, 6)
finish
```

I want Django to execute exactly 1 insert query, and not those selects that do nothing useful. How can I achieve this with a Django QuerySet?

1. I don't want to use a native query
2. I don't want to create an intermediate
   table, since a few Django features don't work with it.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Best regards,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can access the autocreated through model via `Room.users.through`. So:

```
Room.users.through.objects.create(room_id=35, user_id=6)
```

Comment: Exactly that I wanted, easy rep ;)